# Words or phrases for 'credit takers'

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, idiom-requests, pejorative-language

Let say, A and B work in the same office. Every time A talks to B about his idea or working style, B always takes that idea to his boss and acts as if it was his own idea.

What are words, phrases or idioms that I can use to call B?

Comment: You mean like "*a two-faced lying sack of sh!t?*"

Comment: @Jim No. You get no credit for that.

Comment: How about *idea thief*?

Comment: Why doesn't A speak to the boss himself, rather than talking to B? It seems to me as if you are looking at the dynamics of group working relationships which are often far more complex than they might at fist seem. The relationship between people who 'do' and people who 'sell' are explored in depth by Steinbeck in *Of Mice and Men*.

Comment: A thief of intellectual property?

Comment: As Aiken said "Don't worry about people stealing your ideas. If your ideas are any good, you'll have to ram them down people's throats".

Answer (score 1):

According to the [*American Heritage Dictionary*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/steal+(someone's)+thunder), **steal (someone's) thunder** means

> To use, appropriate, or preempt the use of another's idea, especially to one's own advantage and without consent by the originator.

The thief could be called a *thunder stealer*.

Answer (score 0):

The word *plagiarist* will work for you.

Plagiarism is the act of passing off someone else's work as your own.

It is used in much wider contexts than the office environment that you refer to but is perfectly usable here.